# How to correctly use the lodash to group an object inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, lodash

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[ { key: 'particles', value: 'GN' },
  { key: 'particles', value: 'TR' },
  { key: 'wave', value: 'AB' },
  { key: 'sense', value: 'TU' } ]
```

I need to get to something like:

```
[ { system.particles: ['GN', 'TR'] }, system.wave: {'AB'}, system.sense: {'TE'} } ]
```

I have tried to use lodash as I have seen from examples using the groupBy function. But I haven't been able to get what I want, which includes the key name changes.

This is a part of my code:

```
let exo = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(desc, 'key'),
    clist => clist.map(tags => _.omit(desc, ['key'])))
```

But I only get this, which is not what I'm looking for

```
{ particles: [ { value: 'GN' }, { value: 'TR' } ],
  wave: [ { value: 'AB' } ],
  sense: [ { value: 'TU' } ] }
```

Comment: this part `{'GN', 'TR'}` is not valid. you need an array instead.

Comment: how about instead of _.omit(...), you use desc.value?

Comment: @Vortex check my answer is that what you want?

Comment: what is this `system.particles`?

Comment: @NinaScholz you are right, sorry. fixed edit

Comment: @Vinay is a new key name for "particles"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map like this

```js
const data = [
  { key: 'particles', value: 'GN' },
  { key: 'particles', value: 'TR' },
  { key: 'wave', value: 'AB' },
  { key: 'wave', value: 'ABC' },
  { key: 'wave', value: 'ABD' },
  { key: 'sense', value: 'TU' }
];

const groupedData = _.map(_.groupBy(data, 'key'), (value, key) => {
   const newKey = 'system.' + key;

   return {[newKey]: _.map(value, 'value') };
});

console.log(groupedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is s exactly what I'm looking for.
Is there any way to change the key names?
 They are names that are defined from a variable.

I mean for example' particles' to 'system.particles'

Comment: what do you mean by They are names that are defined from a variable?

Comment: something like ``system.${data.key}`` but this format isn't valid inside of the return

Comment: I really appreciate this help, it's entirely what I needed! Thank you